# Javascript GIS - looping through feature.attributes

Tags: javascript, loops, attributes, gis

I am trying to return all attribute names and values from this object

-This function is called after a query is executed, and feature contains the results.
-feature.attributes returns an 'Object' with all of the attribute names.
-featureLayer[counter].fields[i].name works fine

I was under the assumption that feature.attributes was an array. Does anyone have suggestions as to how to return all attribute values from this feature object?

(counter, map, featureLayer and queryContent declared globally)

```
function showFeature(feature,evt) {
    //set symbol
    feature.setSymbol(symbol);

    //construct infowindow title and content
    var attr = feature.attributes;
    var title = "Query";
    queryContent = queryContent + "<div>" + "Layer: " + featureLayer[counter].name + "<br />";

    for(i=0;i<featureLayer[counter].fields.length;i++){
        queryContent = queryContent + featureLayer[counter].fields[i].name + ": " + attr[i] + "<br />" + "<br />" + "</div>";
    }

    counter++;
    map.infoWindow.setTitle(title);
    map.infoWindow.setContent(queryContent);

    (evt) ? map.infoWindow.show(evt.screenPoint,map.getInfoWindowAnchor(evt.screenPoint)) : null;
}
```

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

I found an alternative that works quite well with the arcgis package.

Instead of .attr, you can use [attr]

replace the for loop with:

```
for(i=0;i<featureLayer[counter].fields.length;i++){
   queryContent = queryContent + featureLayer[counter].fields[i].name + ": " + feature.attributes[featureLayer[counter].fields[i].name] + "<br />" + "</div>";
}
```